# Typo3 News: New Records only for news

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news

I am having troubles with News Extension 7.3 in TYPO3 9.5.9!
In the List Module i can only choose "Newsarticle" and "Newstags" as new records. Why is everything else like Pages etc. gone and how can i fix it that everything is shown with the news extension?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a default behaviour of EXT:news. Are you sure that you've choosen the list module and not the news administration module? Did you check if there is another extension, e.g. your sitepackage or theme extension which modifies the behaviour via TSConfig or ext_localconf.php or ext_tables.php? Maybe you can add a screenshot of the current behaviour.

Comment: i am using the list module and not the news administration. i added a screenshot. here you can see what i see if i want to add a new record in a folder. after i deactivate the news plugin everything is working fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've included the Page TS Configuration from news in your root page. This should only be included in the folder where (only) the news records are located. Check your root page for the `EXT:news :: Restrict pages to news records (news)` Page TSConfig.